# Laptop freezes randomly on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: freeze, 23.10

My laptop has been randomly freezing ever since I got it last year and installed Ubuntu on it. I have tried to find the problem but never could. I am now pretty sick of it as it is interfering with my work, and it would be great if I could get some help.

There is no pattern to the freezing. Sometimes it won't happen all day. Sometimes it will happen multiple times in a row after rebooting. It doesn't matter what program I have running. Sometimes it freezes with no programs running. The only way to fix it is by shutting off the laptop manually using the power button and booting it up again.

free -h gives:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       2.9Gi        52Gi       625Mi       8.5Gi        59Gi
Swap:          8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi
```

sysctl vm.swappiness gives:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

swapon -s gives:

```
Filename                Type        Size        Used    Priority
/swap.img                               file        8388604     0   -2
```

My laptop info is:

```
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-03-25 11:21:45

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              HP HP ENVY Laptop 17-ch0xxx
- **Memory:**                                      64.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 × 8
- **Graphics:**                                    Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
- **Disk Capacity:**                               (null)

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            F.12
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.2
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-26-generic
```

Finally, the only thing in my syslogs before the crash is:

```
2024-03-25T11:05:01.599439-07:00 eitan-HPEnvy wpa_supplicant[932]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 6c:c4:9f:c6:00:f0 0
2024-03-25T11:05:01.605680-07:00 eitan-HPEnvy wpa_supplicant[932]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 6c:c4:9f:c5:f9:60 0
2024-03-25T11:05:01.605723-07:00 eitan-HPEnvy wpa_supplicant[932]: wlo1: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 6c:c4:9f:c6:5a:a0 0
```

Please help!