# Please help with understanding crash logs

Tags: freeze, crash, 23.10, logs

I have two crash logs now and I don't understand how I can interpret them. Below is the pastebin of the complete logs.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3xhZ5xWgjr/

This is one of them, I can post the other if it is helpful. The rest of system information is on my other post. [Laptop freezes randomly on Ubuntu 23.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508587/laptop-freezes-randomly-on-ubuntu-23-10). I am desperate for help!

Comment: Lines 1291-1370 shows a kernel crash. When Ubuntu asks you to send the Problem Report, agree.

Comment: @user535733 so this is a hardware compatibility problem? Kind of disappointing I can't fix it myself but will make sure to send a report, thanks!